# How to delete a file saved in a folder via grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am saving a .pdf/.docx file when creating a entry in y grails-app. Now on the click of Delete button I want to remove that entry from DB as well as I also want to delete the .pdf/.docx file from the folder.
**Note : I am saving the path of the file in my DB.**

Answer (score 4):

Deleting file from physical location is as simple as this -

```
def file = new File(/C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg/)   
file.delete()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String filePath = fileDomainObject.filePath
boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  new File(filePath).delete()
if(fileSuccessfullyDeleted ){
    fileDomainObject.delete flush:true
}
else{
    flash.error = "Error in deletion."
    return
}
```